# "Unexpected data found" no retorno da função

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma função que deveria retornar uma json a partir de uma collection gerada por uma query builder.

```
    $today = Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d');
    $tasks = Task::where('date', $today)->whereHas('collaborators', function($q) {

        $q->where('collaborator_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('allocation', '=', 1)
        ->where('accepted', '=', 1)
        ->where('confirm_allocation', '=', 1);

    })->with('event')->get();
```

No entanto sempre que tento retornar o resultado com:

```
    return response()->json($tasks, 200);
```

Aparece-me um erro "Unexpected data found"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao fazer um  Dump and Die na variável $tasks retorna-me os resultados previstos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, o retorno do json é faz surgir o erro "Unexpected data found".
Caso eu retire a relação da query, ou seja o with('event'), os resultados já são retornados correctamente e no formato json, mas preciso mesmo que a relação seja retornada também.

Answer (score 0):

Retirei do Model Event

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
protected $dates = ['date_time_init', 'date_time_end'];
```

Estas linhas de código faziam conflito com

```
public function getDateTimeInitAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['date_time_init'] = Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y H:i');
}

public function getDateTimeEndAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['date_time_end'] = Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y H:i');
}

public function setDateTimeInitAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['date_time_init'] = Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

public function setDateTimeEndAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['date_time_end'] = Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

public function setCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['created_at'] = Carbon::parse($value);
}

public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['updated_at'] = Carbon::parse($value);
}
```